# How to use Ngen.exe in WPF Application?

Tags: ngen

I want to increase start-up performance of WPF pages because it takes more time to load. Is Ngen.exe improve the performance or not and how could I use it in WPF Application

Comment: The same as you would with any other application? This is not specific to WPF.

Answer (score 1):

You can just run NGen on it, but it might not help you as much as you think. If it doesn't, you can always implement a splash screen to make your application seem quicker than it really is.

Comment: Is it effects on all windows or pages in WPF or only startup window?

Comment: It will affect the MSIL->Native code compilation of all your application - pages, windows and everything else. However, WPF has a lot of its own overhead that won't be solved by NGen. Just try it out.

Comment: How can I run it? Actually there are some pages in my application that take a lot of time to load

Comment: Run NGen.exe on your executable file.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned any problem related to create image of WPF app. So looks like that just need manual. Please, check it - [Ngen.exe (Native Image Generator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx).

Moreover I think that you need to check architecture of your app. Move some action to [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) or implement cache on server if you use server.

**If you need more detailed answer - add more details to description of your issue.**